# Mysql how to find count of distinct columns based on another distinct column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this

```
userId   story  novel
1        a      b
1        a      b
1        a      c
1        b      c
1        b      c
2        x      x
2        x      y
2        y      y
3        m      n
4        NULL   NULL
```

How do I find the most story and novel count per user?

What I am looking for is the highest distinct count of story and novel for each user. So if a user has no story then story_count should be 0.

Desired output looks like this

```
userId   story  story_count  novel novel_count
1        a      3            c     3
2        x      2            y     2
3        m      1            n     1
4        NULL   0            NULL  0
```

This is my faulty current attempt

```
SELECT userId, story, COUNT(story) as story_count, novel, COUNT(novel) as novel_count  
FROM logs WHERE user = (SELECT DISTINCT(user)) GROUP BY story, novel;
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on Tim's answer,I provide an upgrade solution

```
create table `logs`(
 userId int,
 story varchar(10),
 novel varchar(10)
);

insert into `logs`(userId,story,novel) values
(1,'a',' b'),
(1 ,'a','c'),
(1 ,'b','c'),
(2 ,'x','x'),
(2 ,'x','y'),
(2 ,'y','y');

SELECT t1.userId,t1.story,t1.story_count,t2.novel,t2.novel_count
FROM
(
SELECT userId, story, COUNT(*) AS story_count,
       RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY userId ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) rn
FROM logs
GROUP BY userId, story
) as t1
join
(
SELECT userId, novel, COUNT(*) AS novel_count,
       RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY userId ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) rn
FROM logs
GROUP BY userId, novel
)as t2
ON t1.userId = t2.userId and t1.rn = t2.rn
WHERE t1.rn =1
```

[**DB Fiddle Demo**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qC8AZqXi8o6pSu2yY9wub3/0)

Comment: Why i am getting this error, is this because of MySQL version? `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(PARTITION BY userId ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) rn
FROM logs
GROUP BY userId, sto' at line 5`

Comment: @mahfujasifn it's because your mysql version does not support [window function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html)

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen Why do you delete your answer?

Answer (score 1):

You should really use a window function if this is possible because thus, you can keep your query much shorter and simpler. If this is not possible and you really need to do it without them, you can also create two subqueries for both the story data and the novel data according to your conditions and then join them. Something like this:

```
SELECT storydata.userId, storydata.story, storydata.counter AS story_count,
noveldata.novel, noveldata.counter AS novel_count  
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT l.userId, l.story, sub.counter
FROM logs l
JOIN
(SELECT userId, COALESCE(MAX(story_count),0) AS counter
FROM
(SELECT userId, story,
COUNT(story) as story_count  
FROM logs 
GROUP BY userId, story) sub
GROUP BY userId) sub
ON l.userId = sub.userId
GROUP BY l.userId, l.story
HAVING COUNT(l.userId) = sub.counter OR l.story IS NULL) AS storydata
JOIN
(SELECT noveldata.userId, noveldata.novel, noveldata.counter AS counter
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT l.userId, l.novel, sub.counter
FROM logs l
JOIN
(SELECT userId, COALESCE(MAX(novel_count),0) AS counter
FROM
(SELECT userId, novel,
COUNT(novel) as novel_count  
FROM logs 
GROUP BY userId, novel) sub
GROUP BY userId) sub
ON l.userId = sub.userId
GROUP BY l.userId, l.novel
HAVING COUNT(l.userId) = sub.counter OR l.novel IS NULL) AS noveldata) AS noveldata
ON storydata.userId = noveldata.userId;
```

But as you can see, this will become very complicated although it will produce the correct outcome. See here:
[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/EO2xlaxL)

Therefore, I once again highly recommend to use a DB version that provides window functions.

Comment: Actually i want count highest distinct count of story and novel for each user. Now if i add another user with `3 m n`, then output should contain row like `3 m 1 n 1`. But this SQL does not show this row

Comment: Could you please edit your question with more and better sample input and outcome? I guess you can just replace the > 1 condition with MAX. But I don't want to change my answer as long as the requirement is not 100% clear.

Comment: Please check my updated question with detailed sample data

Comment: Updated the answer according to your requirements.

Comment: unfortunately still it is not working,  I changed input and it broke https://dbfiddle.uk/lE0f8ItJ

Comment: In my opinion, your original question has already been well answered. If you change your samples and requirements, it's just logical answers might no longer work. Please accept one of the correct answers and create a new question if you need further assistance. We can't update answers everytime you are changing your data and requirement. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works:

```
select story.userid, story, story_count, novel, novel_count 
from
    (
        select userid, story, count(*) story_count, 
        row_number() over (partition by userid order by count(*) desc) rown_num
        from logs
        where row_num=1
    )story
left join 
    (
        select userid, novel, count(*) novel_count, 
        row_number() over (partition by userid order by count(*) desc) rown_num
        from logs
        where row_num=1
    )novel on novel.userid=story.userid
```

Comment: getting this error `MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition by userid order by count(*) desc) rown_num
        from logs
      ' at line 5`

Comment: Even after changing column name to `userid`

Comment: Mysql version is `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.40, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper`

Comment: It does not work, also not with MySQL 8.x, see: https://dbfiddle.uk/oz5SzR_x

Comment: You cannot use `rown_num` in the WHERE because it's an alias, and the `GROUP BY` is missing, see: https://dbfiddle.uk/DGTOqoGd

Answer (score 0):

Try the following for MySQL 5.7:

```
set @u=0;
set @tot=0;
set @rn=1;
select userid, story, story_count, novel, novel_count
from
(
  select userid, story, story_count, novel, novel_count,  
         if(@u<>userid or (@rn=1 and @tot=tot_cnt), @rn:=1, @rn:= @rn+1) rnk,
         @u:=userid, @tot:=tot_cnt
  from
  (
    select T.userid, T.story, T.story_count, D.novel, D.novel_count, 
           T.story_count+D.novel_count tot_cnt
    from
    (
      select userid, story, count(story) story_count  
      from table_name group by userid, story
    ) T 
    join
    (
      select userid, novel, count(novel) novel_count  
      from table_name group by userid, novel
    ) D
    on T.userid=D.userid
  ) joined_counts
  order by userid, tot_cnt desc
) ranked_counts
where rnk = 1
order by userid
```

This query will select all the equal highest counts of story and novel for each user, if you want to select only one highest count (from the multiple equal highest counts) then replace the if statement with this `if(@u<>userid, @rn:=1, @rn:= @rn+1) rnk`.

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/NLXdqFLE).